# Custom domain SSL certificate for Azure websites in Shared mode

Tags: ssl, azure, azure-web-app-service

How can I upload a SSL certificate for an Azure Web Site running in **Shared** mode?

Microsoft states that Custom Domain SSL certificates are supported for both **Shared** and Reserved Web Sites - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/ (click the SSL certificates tab) , but I can't seem to find any place to upload a certificate when the site is running in Shared mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect, SSL is **only available in Reserved** at the moment and is in a preview capacity

Comment: Also confirmed - it doesn't appear **Shared** mode allows SSL yet, but **Reserved** does. [MSDN Forum has an interesting chain following the SSL support progress](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/992d419a-9a59-44c8-b9a3-db49f7687d25).

Comment: For those wondering, this is still the case as of 12/4/13: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-manage-websites/ (do a search for SSL)